# toggle class when div hit the top of the browser on scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following script to toggle a class when the page is scrolled. it makes one of the navigation to become fixed. i would now like to add an addition task when a div at the bottom of the page hits the top of the browser the class is again toggle back.

```
   var $window = $(window),
       $stickyEl = $('#the-sticky-div'),
       elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

   $window.scroll(function() {
        $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
    });
```

some thing like maybe?

```
   var $window = $(window),
       $stickyEl = $('#the-sticky-div'),
       $stickyElbot = $('#footerdiv'),
       elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;
       elBot = $stickyElbot.offset().top;

   $window.scroll(function() {
        $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
        $stickyElbot.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elBot);
    });
```

Comment: could you state your goal more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.scrollTop()`, documentation: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

For example:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){

    if ( $(window).scrollTop() === 0 ){ 
      // The browser is at the top of the page
      $("#element").addClass(".doe");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** I think you should check for offset().top  inside window scroll event not outside

**2nd:** you can use something like

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
     if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('footer').offset().top){
      console.log('reached to top');
     }
 });
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4rf2s3oa/1/)